# How does Firebase generate the Uid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My question is how does Firebase generate the Uid? Is it generated from the app installation on the cellphone or maybe it is based on the login provider via email, Facebook, Google or the other ones that Firebase provide?

Comment: The `uid` is a random id generated by the Firebase server side system.  That `uid` does not change once the account is created.  When you delete an account, the `uid` is also deleted.  The `uid` is how you want to identify your various users.  Typically, developers have a `users` node under root where the `uid`'s are stored.

Comment: I think the comment above here from @RonRoyston is the most complete answer and what I want to know! Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Firebase User ID (often called uid) is an opaque identifier for a user account. It has no connection to the underlying identity provider(s) for the account and should be treated as an opaque value.

As per [IndieWeb](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwin95mmsoHtAhWzwzgGHR1zBJUQFjABegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Findieweb.org%2Fopaque&usg=AOvVaw3LpKCl3XILetw5X2VuPdz9)

> “Opaque” is a term often used to refer to data such as URIs or other identifiers. An identifier is opaque if it provides no information about the thing it identifies other than being a seemingly random string or number.

Comment: And what happens when the user logs out of the application, and enters another account, does Firebase detects the log out and change the uid, or is it better not to map the uid with the email for authentication?

Comment: If the user logs out, the Firebase client wipes the token. So it effectively forgets all about the user. You seem to have a very specific behavior in mind, so I highly recommend trying it and basing your approach on your findings there.

Comment: Is the installation_uuid I see as a field in BigQuery the same thing as what is being set with [setUserIdentifier](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/CrashlyticsCore.html#setUserIdentifier(java.lang.String)), and comes back with [getIdentifier](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/CrashlyticsCore.html#getIdentifier())? If not, should we be able to read it in any way?

Comment: Feel free to answer [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760612/how-does-firebase-generate-the-uid#comment100679261_38766107) in https://superuser.com/questions/1460896/firebase-crashlytics-unique-id

Answer (score 2):

UUID is autogenerated based on timestamp and some entropy. UUID's can be sorted based on creation time, this helps to maintain indexes in Firebase.

UUID is not some hash of for example the email address, or facebook id or other. By removing all meaning from the uid itself, it is not dependent on any underlying properties and those properties can freely changed.

If you want to use custom UID you need to be consistent. It is recommended to not tight together user id creation and login property of some sort because the property can change, and you will have inconsistent user id.

Comment: I think OP is asking about Firebase UIDs, which are the keys Firebase Authentication uses for identifying a user.

Comment: UIDs in firebase are UUIDs as well.

Comment: UIDs are nowadays indeed UUIDs. But what you are describing are not UUIDs. The things based on timestamps + random data are called [push ids](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) (because they are generated by calling `push()`).