# Will the UID of the user deleted from the Firebase be reused for the new user?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I know that the Uid of authenticated user on firebase is unique.

But, I can not be sure that uid of the deleted user will not be re used by the new user.

I could not find an explanation for this.

I need experience or information related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the uid will always be unique. It is actually based on the timestamp and other factors so it will be unique.

Info on how firebase generates it :
[How does Firebase generate the Uid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760612/how-does-firebase-generate-the-uid)

And about their uniqueness:
https://towardsdatascience.com/are-uuids-really-unique-57eb80fc2a87

If you still want to set your custom uid for a user for any analytics purpose :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!!!!  It was really necessary and helpful information.