# Why does userUUID return undefined?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm expecting to export userUUID as a value but it return undefined, I tried every solution i think about or found in the web but ain't no luck

anynone can help me with this?

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-analytics.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, setPersistence,     browserLocalPersistence } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-auth.js";
import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebaseConfig.js";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);

let userUUID;

console.log("Firebase initialized.");

setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
  .then(() =\> {
  console.log("User persistence set to browserLocalPersistence.");

    const signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form');
    const loginForm = document.getElementById('login-form');

    // Handle SignUp Event
    signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const email = document.getElementById('signup-email').value;
      const password = document.getElementById('signup-password').value;

      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          userUUID = userCredential.user.uid;
          console.log("userUUID (Signup):", userUUID);
          window.location.href = "index.html";
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error during signup:", error);
        });
    });
    // Handle Login Event
    loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const email = document.getElementById('login-email').value;
      const password = document.getElementById('login-password').value;

      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          userUUID = userCredential.user.uid;
          console.log("userUUID (Login):", userUUID);
          window.location.href = "index.html";
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          document.getElementById("login-error").textContent = "Login failed. Please check your credentials and try again.";
          console.log("Error during login:", error);
        });
    });

})
.catch((error) =\> {
console.log("Error setting user persistence:", error);
});

export { userUUID };
```

*export userUUID not working it return undefined and i don't know why*

I'm expecting to export userUUID as a value but it return undefined, I tried every solution i think about or found in the web but ain't no luck

Comment: Where exactly are you importing UUID? Its is not automatically included! Import it then use as the docs say: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid     Also check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760612/how-does-firebase-generate-the-uid

Comment: It's from firebase @JulesUK

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: You can't export a value that's computed asynchronously via a promise.  The best you can do is export a promise that becomes fulfilled with the value, and the importer has to wait on the promise to get a hold of the value to know whenever it becomes available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that calling `.then(() =>` will not execute the closure that you pass to it immediately. The code flow will essentially be this:

```
// [your initialization code]
let userUUID = undefined;
setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence) -+
export { userUUID };                           |
                                               |
// [JavaScript engine runs other code]         |
then(() => {     <-----------------------------+
  console.log("User persistence set to browserLocalPersistence.");
  ...
```

See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: I figure it out, thanks everybody :)